# Keeping the name of the value instead of getting the variable name instead of its value

Tags: javascript

I have an array of strings, where some elements are composed of a variable + some string. I need to get the elements of the array as they are in the js/ts file. I don't want JavaScript to evaluate the variable:

```
let prefix = 'Week';
let myArray = [prefix + '2nd', prefix + 'third', etc.]

myArray.map(element => console.log(element))
```

I need a way to console log "prefix + 'second'" instead of 'Week 2nd'
I want the output to be the variable name 'prefix' not its value 'Week'

Comment: So type `'prefix'` instead of `prefix`? It's never going to output "second" when you type "2nd" though...

Comment: I don't think you can just console.log the variable name + 'string' at least not in js, not if names are dynamic at least

Comment: Unfortunately, in my scenario, I need to get the array without the varaibles being evaluated

Answer (score 0):

You will need to put your variable in a string instead, else it will always be evaluated...

```js
    let myArray = [`prefix + '2nd'`, `prefix + 'third'`]
    
    myArray.map(element => console.log(element))
```